# Hide long text within Select using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-select

I have a select box that has some text that overflows. It doesn't look too good and I want to find a way, using CSS, to solve the issue.

Code:

```css
select {
    height: 2.4375rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
    margin: 0 0 1rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-family: inherit;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #0a0a0a;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="32" height="24" viewBox="0 0 32 24"><polygon points="0,0 32,0 16,24" style="fill: rgb%2851, 51, 51%29"></polygon></svg>');
    background-size: 9px 6px;
    background-position: right center;
    background-origin: content-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  /* Not in my code but added for demo to simulate select in a small container: */
    max-width:130px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
  <option value="34380969">Rescue </option>
  <option value="34380970">Education </option>
  <option value="34380971">Health &amp; Genetics </option>
  <option value="34380972">Endowment </option>
  <option selected value="34380973">Where it is Most Needed</option>
</select>
```

When you run the snippet you will see `Where it is Most Needed` is cutoff. I would prefer it to cutoff and not cover the arrow. Be great if it could fade off (maybe with gradients?).

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.

Add some right padding to the `select` element, for example, 30px, and set a `width` value, say 200px.

Then, adjust the background position so that the horizontal offset is the width minus the padding, 170px.

You can adjust the numbers to get the styling that you need.

```css
select {
  height: 2.4375rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #cacaca;
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #0a0a0a;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="32" height="24" viewBox="0 0 32 24"><polygon points="0,0 32,0 16,24" style="fill: rgb%2851, 51, 51%29"></polygon></svg>');
  background-size: 9px 6px;
  background-position: 170px center;
  background-origin: content-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /* Not in my code but added for demo to simulate select in a small container: */
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
  <option value="34380969">Rescue</option>
  <option value="34380970">Education</option>
  <option value="34380971">Health &amp; Genetics</option>
  <option value="34380972">Endowment</option>
  <option selected value="34380973">Where it is Most Needed</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hack. Increase right padding and change image background position to percentage.

Hope this Help!

```css
select {
    padding-right: 15px !important;
    height: 2.4375rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
    margin: 0 0 1rem;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-family: inherit;
    line-height: normal;
    color: #0a0a0a;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="32" height="24" viewBox="0 0 32 24"><polygon points="0,0 32,0 16,24" style="fill: rgb%2851, 51, 51%29"></polygon></svg>');
    background-size: 9px 6px;
    background-position: 112% 50%;
    background-origin: content-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  /* Not in my code but added for demo to simulate select in a small container: */
    max-width:130px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
  <option value="34380969">Rescue </option>
  <option value="34380970">Education </option>
  <option value="34380971">Health &amp; Genetics </option>
  <option value="34380972">Endowment </option>
  <option selected value="34380973">Where it is Most Needed</option>
</select>
```